# Split XML file - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python 3 and am trying to split an XML file into multiple valid XML files with the header (any lines before the first <changeset) replicated for each file. And footer.

**INPUT EXAMPLE:**

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.namespacedbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.namespace-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://namespaceXMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.namespacedbchangelog-ext http://www.namespacedbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.namespacedbchangelog http://www.namespacedbchangelog/dbchangel.xsd">
    <changeSet author="oracle (generated)" id="1594342324345277">
        <createView fullDefinition="true" viewName="VIEW1">
            CONTENTS OF THE VIEW
       </createView>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="oracle (generated)" id="159423231995822477">
        <createTable tableName="TEST1">
            CONTENTS OF THE TABLE
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="oracle (generated)" id="1534129423123477">
        <createTable tableName="TEST2">
            CONTENTS OF THE TABLE
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**OUTPUT 1** File name: 1594342324345277-createView-VIEW1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.namespacedbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.namespace-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://namespaceXMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.namespacedbchangelog-ext http://www.namespacedbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.namespacedbchangelog http://www.namespacedbchangelog/dbchangel.xsd">
    <changeSet author="oracle (generated)" id="1594342324345277">
        <createView fullDefinition="true" viewName="VIEW1">
            CONTENTS OF THE VIEW
       </createView>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**OUTPUT 2** File name: 159423231995822477-createTable-TEST1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.namespacedbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.namespace-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://namespaceXMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.namespacedbchangelog-ext http://www.namespacedbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.namespacedbchangelog http://www.namespacedbchangelog/dbchangel.xsd">
    <changeSet author="oracle (generated)" id="159423231995822477">
        <createTable tableName="TEST1">
            CONTENTS OF THE TABLE
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**OUTPUT 3:** File name: 1534129423123477-createTable-TEST2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.namespacedbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.namespace-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://namespaceXMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.namespacedbchangelog-ext http://www.namespacedbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.namespacedbchangelog http://www.namespacedbchangelog/dbchangel.xsd">
    <changeSet author="oracle (generated)" id="1534129423123477">
        <createTable tableName="TEST2">
            CONTENTS OF THE TABLE
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
xml = '''
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.namespacedbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.namespace-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://namespaceXMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.namespacedbchangelog-ext http://www.namespacedbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.namespacedbchangelog http://www.namespacedbchangelog/dbchangel.xsd">
    <changeSet author="oracle (generated)" id="1594342324345277">
        <createView fullDefinition="true" viewName="VIEW1">
            CONTENTS OF THE VIEW
       </createView>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="oracle (generated)" id="159423231995822477">
        <createTable tableName="TEST1">
            CONTENTS OF THE TABLE
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="oracle (generated)" id="1534129423123477">
        <createTable tableName="TEST2">
            CONTENTS OF THE TABLE
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
databaseChangeLog = doc.databaseChangeLog # Get root node
changeSets = databaseChangeLog.selects('changeSet')
for changeSet in changeSets:
    child = changeSet.child # Get the child node
    fileName = "{0}-{1}-{2}.xml".format(changeSet.id, child.tag,
                                        child['viewName'] or child['tableName'])
    databaseChangeLog.setContent(changeSet) # Replace node
    utils.saveFile(fileName, doc.html) # Save file
    print (fileName)
```

Reslut:

```
1594342324345277-createView-VIEW1.xml
159423231995822477-createTable-TEST1.xml
1534129423123477-createTable-TEST2.xml
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples